# Can I force a PS variable passed by Invoke-SqlCmd to be parsed as part of the base sql in the target file?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm new to Powershell. I have a bunch of stored procedures that are exactly the same except they reside in different schemas and target different names. Very simply, they look like this (real procs are much longer)

```
CREATE PROC [a].[ProcessTable] AS UPDATE a.Table_a
CREATE PROC [b].[ProcessTable] AS UPDATE b.Table_b
CREATE PROC [c].[ProcessTable] as UPDATE c.Table_c
```

I wanted to create just one file (call it 'FileWithStoredProc.sql') with the base stored procedure and then use an outer powershell script to execute it multiple times:

1. loop through an array of {a, b, c, ... n}
2. use Invoke-SQLcmd -inputfile "FileWithBasicStoredProc.sql" -Variable $args
3. Then in my target file, have something like

```
CREATE PROC [$(arg1)].[ProcessTable] AS UPDATE $(arg1).Table_$(arg1)
```

I can now see that it's fine as long as I want to use $(arg1) as a string, say

```
print 'Creating stored proc ' + $(arg1) + '.ProcessTable'
```

But I want the target file to intepret my variable as part of a sql object name.

How do I do this? I cannot redesign/rename my SQL objects, and since the procedure is quite long, with a lot of these schema swaps, I don't want to use the -Query parameter in my powershell wrapper. Is what I want possible, without changing everything into a giant 'exec sql' string? I'd like to keep these target sql files relatively easy to read and modify.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic statements to do this. I don't make use of the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` module, so I wouldn't want to hazard a guess at the syntax required from there to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just reading the file into a string, replacing the values, and executing the string.